# Cable connection password

Tags: windows-xp, passwords

Hello I have a problem with my internet connection password, because I work late every day I couldn't be home when my cable internet was setup-ed by tech guys so I asked my neighbor to open my house and show them my computer for me. Now I want to check my bandwidth for this month and I can't because I have no password for this connection, and my internet provider refuses to give me the password over the phone, and I can't make to their offices during the work hours because I work late as I said, is there a way to unmask this password stored already somewhere on my computer? Here is the picture to give you better idea what I mean. I'm using XP.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not understand why they cannot give it to you over the phone - I would personally ask them again or ask to speak to a manager.

That being said, most ISP's give you either an email or letter when you join stating account details. Can you find that?

Anyway, now for the Superuser answer and what will hopefully solve it for you in no time! There is a utility by [Nirsoft](http://www.nirsoft.net) called [Dialupass](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/dialupass.html) which should show you **all** DUN (Dial up networking) stored passwords on your system.

[image]

Comment: "most ISP's give you either an email or letter when you join stating account details. Can you find that?" I think this is the case for me as well but unfortunately my neighbor didn't leave anything for me. And the reason why they refuse to give me by phone is because they don't have my personal ID card number, they have my neighbors because the guys took the credentials from him, but anyways this cool software works thank you